# print just errors when you run a large number of insert statement via sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I need to load a table with thousands of records.

I produced a .sql file like this:

```
INSERT into TABLE(OLD,NEW) VALUES('A1','B1');
INSERT into TABLE(OLD,NEW) VALUES('A2','B2');
INSERT into TABLE(OLD,NEW) VALUES('A3','B3');
(...)
INSERT into TABLE(OLD,NEW) VALUES('A500000','B500000');
COMMIT;
```

sqlplus prints **every** statement with the output "1 row created."

This caused a very large and unuseful log... (very unuseful... on our change platform, logs are truncated after 50'000 rows...)

How can I log just the statement in error?

Comment: You can use external table to load comma separated file that's has  easy way to handle errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`set feedback off`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG079) at the start of your script:

> SET FEEDBACK OFF also turns off the statement confirmation messages such as 'Table created' and 'PL/SQL procedure successfully completed' that are displayed after successful SQL or PL/SQL statements.

If you're running a script in a non-interactive session you might also want to [`set echo off`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG075).

Comment: Error messages are not affected by `feedback` or `echo` settings. If there are a large number of insert statements, you might also `set serveroutput off` and `alter session set cursor_sharing = force;` You could also set [`errorlogging`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-939BF6EA-F58A-4CA2-A852-94C5D721D273) to capture errors in a table.

Comment: Yes, I tried it! perfect! The script maybe is also faster.

Answer (score -1):

Use just one `INSERT` statement with all the `VALUES`

```
INSERT into TABLE(OLD,NEW) VALUES
    ('A1','B1'),
    ('A2','B2'),
    ...
    ('A500000','B500000')
;
```

Log will be `500000 rows created.`

Comment: Oracle doesn't support that syntax. I'm curious though - in a system that does, what happens if one (or more) of the rows can't be inserted? Are the other 49999 still inserted successfully, and you get a message about the one(s) that were not? Or do they all fail and a single error is reported?

Comment: All statements needs to be independent, with this sintax an error will fail all the insets.